# Clone failed remote error from Google Cloud

Tags: android, git, android-studio

Clone always failed when check out from google cloud, but clone from github always succeed, I'm using mac sierra and git 2.8.4.0. anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the answer, but i'm installing google cloud sdk, and it work